# How to run multi level segmentation for LULC in process tree, eCognition software

Tags: classification, sentinel-2, rule-based, ecognition, image-segmentation

Can we run the eCognition  multi level (level 1 ,level 2,...) segmentation and classification in the same process tree? I want different outputs to show for each levels in a process tree. I'm in the intial learning stage of eCognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to GIS-SE

The Object-oriented image analysis within eCognition allows to create multiple image objects levels simultaneously in its 'Process tree' pan. You can perform segmentation from pixel level to coarse resolution object level to facilitate onward image classification on defined object levels each representing a meaningful structure in an image.

[image: Object hierarchy levels]

According to the eCognition user guide (accessible within installed version) there are two steps to create image object levels;

1- Applying a segmentation algorithm using the pixel-level domain will create a new
level. Image object levels are usually added above an existing ones, although some
algorithms let you specify whether new layers are created above or below existing
ones

2- Using the Copy Image Object Level algorithm

Here is an illustration to help you create image object levels within eCognition process tree pan. Please note that spatial resolution of image and intended object identification should be considered while creating multiple image object levels.
[image: Process tree]

As illustrated, you can define classes based on created object levels for your intended LULC classification.

Comment: Thank you sir..l'll  sure go through it and try